# parser for developing c++ code coverage tool

Tags: c++, code-coverage

I am developing a c++ code coverage tool. Are there any tools available for developing code coverage applications like parsers, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest that you look at the existing compilers and use their parsing abilities. For example there's [clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) which already implements static code analysis of some form. Or you could use the built-in parser of the GNU Compilers/g++. IIRC, the new Visual Studio 2010 SDK also allows you to tap directly into the online compiler (that's also used for the new intellisense).

Comment: +1, if only because clang is built as several libraries, and therefore if you wish to build your own code coverage tool, you can just let the library build a full representation of the code (AST) and exploit it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

See my paper [Branch Coverage Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages Made Easy](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf) which describes how to build test coverage tools using a program transformation system, by parsing source text, building an AST, and applying rewrite rules to insert test coverage probes, and prettyprinting the modified source code for compilation/execution/test probe data collection.

While the technique works with any system that can parse and prettyprint C++, as general rule these are hard to find, because parsing C++ is difficult.  The paper particularly focuses on our [our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html), which has full [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html), and for which we have built a [C++ Test Coverage tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CppTestCoverage.html).